# Hyperledger network generated by hurley

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hurley

How can I change the version on docker images downloaded by hurley when running npm run env:start ?
I would like to ask hurley to download v 2.2.0 but it keeps downlaoding v1.4.0 ... I tried to change in docker-compose.yaml and other config files, I ask docker to remove all existing images but no way ....

Comment: Apparently hurley is switching the version value within the docker-compose.yaml back to 1.4.0 itself when running npm env:start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [readme file](https://github.com/worldsibu/hurley?ref=hurley_launch#get-version) Hurley supports Hyperledger 1.4 networks. I don't think forcing the download of version 2.0 would be enough since there are major changes between the two versions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. yes I know but from my understanding hurley is just creating automatically a peer/orderer network, channels and registering users. I just use it to create dev environments so it should be ok. But it might be impossible to change...

Comment: Even on standard setup (without hurley), i have a line like "image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:$IMAGE_TAG" in the yaml file I still don't know where to change the value of IMAGE_TAG ...

Comment: Sounds like env_var (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/upgrading_your_components.html#set-command-environment-variables)

Comment: I think that when you run "npm env:start" it calls some script inside your node_modules directory. Try searching for something like start.sh. It should set the environment variable for the fabric version.

Comment: I manage to fix it using a .env file. Thanks for your help.